# Laravel resource groupby the result

Tags: php, laravel

I have resource API that gives me the result but I want to group them based on relationship model.

## Code

`controller`

```
$outlet = Outlet::where('slug', $slug)->with(['barcodes.product', 'damages', 'images'])->first();
```

`result`

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Outlet One",
        "slug": "outlet-one",
        "address": "Jl Raya Bogor No.200",
        "cover": null,
        "phone": "0211111112",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "sku": "AB001SU",
                "serial_number": 5245412185,
                "price": 120000,
                "discount": null,
                "product": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Product One",
                    "slug": "product-one",
                    "stock": "70",
                    "cover": null,
                    "description": "This is first product description.",
                    "sku": "AB001SU",
                    "price": 120000,
                    "discount": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "sku": "FD51",
                "serial_number": 778516,
                "price": 75300,
                "discount": 5300,
                "product": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Product One",
                    "slug": "product-one",
                    "stock": "70",
                    "cover": null,
                    "description": "This is first product description.",
                    "sku": "AB001SU",
                    "price": 120000,
                    "discount": null
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "sku": "7609FS",
                "serial_number": 232547544,
                "price": 35900,
                "discount": null,
                "product": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Product Two",
                    "slug": "product-two",
                    "stock": "120",
                    "cover": null,
                    "description": "This is second product description.",
                    "sku": "FRY8016",
                    "price": 450000,
                    "discount": 50000
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "message": "Outlet retrieved successfully."
}
```

> As you can see in `products": [...]` id `1 and 2` are belong to `Product One` is that possible for me to group by my `barcodes.product` based on `product` model?

## Update

To be more clear; What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
{
        "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Outlet One",
            "slug": "outlet-one",
            "address": "Jl Raya Bogor No.200",
            "cover": null,
            "phone": "0211111112",
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Product One",
                    "slug": "product-one",
                    "stock": "70",
                    "cover": null,
                    "description": "This is first product description.",
                    "sku": "AB001SU",
                    "price": 120000,
                    "discount": null
                    "barcodes": {  // now barcodes are grouped by prodcuts
                        "id": 1,
                        "sku": "AB001SU",
                        "serial_number": 5245412185,
                        "price": 120000,
                        "discount": null,
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "sku": "FD51",
                        "serial_number": 778516,
                        "price": 75300,
                        "discount": 5300,
                    },
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Product Two",
                    "slug": "product-two",
                    "stock": "120",
                    "cover": null,
                    "description": "This is second product description.",
                    "sku": "FRY8016",
                    "price": 450000,
                    "discount": 50000
                    "barcodes": { // now barcodes are grouped by prodcuts
                        "id": 3,
                        "sku": "7609FS",
                        "serial_number": 232547544,
                        "price": 35900,
                        "discount": null,
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "message": "Outlet retrieved successfully."
    }
```

## Update 2

`Outlet model`

```
public function barcodes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Barcode::class, 'outlet_products');
}
```

`Barcode model`

```
public function outlets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Outlet::class, 'outlet_products');
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Shizzen83 right now my barcodes data are uppercase and product detail under each of them right? now i want group my barcodes based on products and barcodes goes under product so product one would have 2 barcodes and product two would have one barcode

Comment: @Shizzen83 updated my question, sorry i can't make the question more clear than that :/

Comment: Please share your Outlet model and I think I'll be able to help you.

Comment: Ok working on it

Comment: You need to relationship corresponding `Outlet->Product->Barcode` like this

Comment: @A.ANoman the barcodes have (product_id) and `outlet_products` table have (outlet_id , barcode_id) so relationship is actually between outlet and barcode not outlet and products.

Comment: In your relationship is correct. First retrieve `Outlet` then retrieve `Barcode` then retrieve Barcode related product. But your desired output is not that. Your desired output look like this `Outlet->Product->Barcode`.

Comment: @A.ANoman yes :)

Comment: @A.ANoman found something like this `$user = User::with(['messages' => function($query) {
            $query->select('messages.user_id');
            $query->groupBy('user_id');
        }])->get();` but not sure if it could be useful in my case, any idea?

Comment: I think your relationship is ok. But fullfill your desired output just in your `Outlet` Model create another relation with `Outlet and Product` then everything is fine @mafortis

Answer (score 1):

Never tried something like this but you maybe could do this in your `Outlet` model

```php
use App\Http\Resources\ProductsResource;

public function getProductsAttribute()
{
    $barcodes = $this->barcodes
        ->loadMissing('product')
        ->makeHidden('product');

    $products = $barcodes->pluck('product')->keyBy('id');

    $groupedBarcodes = $barcodes->groupBy(function ($barcode) {
            return $barcode->product->id;
        });

    return ProductsResource::collection($products->map(function ($product, $id) use ($groupedBarcodes) {
        return $product->setAttribute('barcodes', $groupedBarcodes[$id]);
    }))->resolve();
}
```

What is your resource output with that?

Comment: what should i call in my controller to get `getProductsAttribute`?

Comment: It's automatically called thanks to `appends` property https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: it says `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::map() must be callable, string given, called in C:\\laragon\\www\\ims-web\\app\\Outlet.php on line 47` line 47 is `$products = $barcodes->map('product')->keyBy('id');`

Comment: Edited, replaced `map` by `pluck`

Comment: this return data but it requires me avoid using my resource api.  currently my code is like: `'data' => new OutletsResource($outlet),` but if i want to use your model code (which is working fine) i should use `'data' => $outlet,` that means i would have lots of extra data that are not useful to me. any idea on that?

Comment: honestly, have no idea. :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212007/discussion-between-shizzen83-and-mafortis).

Comment: this is the data based on your code (minus) resource file https://www.codepile.net/pile/JoWzp5Vy  and this is my data (minus your code) based on resource file https://www.codepile.net/pile/BELRwena

Answer (score 0):

In your `Outlet` Model write this

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'product_id','id');
}
```

In your `Product` Model write this

```
public function barcodes(){
    return $this->hasMany(Barcode::class,'barcode_id','id');
}
```

Then for your query just write this

```
$outlet = Outlet::where('slug', $slug)->products()->barcodes()->with(['your_field'])->first();
```

Comment: thanks, but i do not have `product_id` column in my `outlet` table

Comment: Welcome @mafortis and I know that

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::products()

Comment: First execute this command `composer dump-autoload` then 
First try this in `tinker`. Then try in production.